# How to visualize first-stage in IV regression?

Tags: regression, stata, instrumental-variable

I know what matters is the F-Statistic, but for a presentation it would also be nice to add a plot that visually shows the first stage. How to best visualize that?

Say you have an outcome $Y$, exogenous controls $X$, a continuous endogenous variable $M$ and a continuous, valid instrument $Z$ with the second and first stage

$Y = \alpha_1 + \beta X'+ \theta M + \varepsilon_1$

$M = \alpha_2 + \beta X'+ \eta Z+ \varepsilon_2$

Would it be sensible to do an added variable plot (`avplot`) of the first stage, ie regressing $X'$ on $Z$ and then plotting the residuals against $M$?

I have also seen people plotting the prediction errors from the first stage directly, should be similar right? The partial correlation plot seems more meaningful to me though.